# Center elements over img

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have "Hello" and the black box on the right centered exactly on the image. **I dont want to use** `position: absolute;` **and** `top: %;`. Please help me :(

How it looks now: https://imgur.com/a/vY4Qcpm

How I want it to look: https://imgur.com/a/ywkqrO2

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0">

        <img id="background" src="img/background.jpeg">
        <div class="middle-part">
            <p id="text">Hello</span></p>
            <div id="field">
                <div id="field-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.middle-part {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
}
#text {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 6px;

    font-size: 50px;
}
#field {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#field-content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;

    width: 380px;
    height: 275px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

With `position: absolute;` and `top: %;` it seems to work but I am searching for a better solution.

I also tried to put the `img` into the `middle-part` below while using `justify-content: center;` but it won't work either.

Comment: I guess there's css transform:translate - not sure how that could be "more responsive" (a phrase you've now removed)

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes I already testet it, but it's still not fully centered if I add `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to `#text {...`.  Seems like I'm reaching people, I thought no one saw my question at first. Am pretty new to HTML, CSS and Stackoverflow :)

Comment: You got an answer below - not sure why they put it in a codepen

Comment: Don't expect instant answers here; it can take a day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `<section>` element with a height of `80vh`, use flexbox to position the contents, and reference the image in CSS as the `background-image`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.s1 {
  height: 80vh;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/85/1280/720);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.middle-part {
  width: 1300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#text {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}

#field-content {
  width: 190px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="s1">
  <div class="middle-part">
      <p id="text">Hello</p>
      <div id="field">
          <div id="field-content"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: having trouble position those elements just right?

Comment: haha i did, but i've fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

To place another element above another, you basically would want to use `position` having the parent element have a value of `relative` and the child `absolute` as so:

```
<div class="parent">
 <img class="random-img" src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/1000/657/147/random-hd-wallpaper-thumb.jpg" alt="random" />
 <h3 class="child">Hello world!</h3>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.random-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
}
```

Find your solution in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Despenzz/pen/xxMQaKR) and adjust it to suit your needs

Comment: was quite disconcerting to notice you used the image with the "Hello" and black box for your codepen - thought you did something really weird :p

Comment: Yeah! I used the wrong img url. I have changed it though. Thanks for spotting that